# Lambda with if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, lambda

Let say I have a list called "y_pred", I want to write a lambda function to change the value to 0  if the value is less than 0.

Before: `y_pred=[1,2,3,-1]`

After: `y_pred=[1,2,3,0]`

I wrote something like this, and return an error message

```
y_pred=list(lambda x: 0 if y_pred[x]<0 else y_pred[x])    
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You can use list comprehension for this `y_pred=[i if i >= 0 else 0 for i in y_pred]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want an expression (`a if cond else b`) mapped over your list:

```
y_pred_before = [1, 2, 3, -1]
y_pred_after = list(map(lambda x: 0 if x < 0 else x, y_pred_before))
# => [1, 2, 3, 0]
```

A shorter form of the same thing is a list comprehension (`[expr for item in iterable]`):

```
y_pred_after = [0 if x < 0 else x for x in y_pred_before]
```

---

Your error *"TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable"* comes from the fact that `list()` tries to iterate over its argument. You've given it a lambda, i.e. a function. And functions are not iterable.

You meant to iterate over the *results* of the function. That's what `map()` does.

Comment: Even simpler: `[max(0, y) for y in y_pred]`

Comment: @flakes True, but this was not meant to be code golf. :) I wanted to keep the OP's ternary.

Comment: Just pointing it out! I did +1 the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy (assuming that using `lambda` is not a requirement):

```
import numpy as np
y_pred = np.array(y_pred)
y_pred[y_pred < 0] = 0
y_pred
```

Output:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this with list comprehension:

```
y_pred=[x if x>0 else 0 for x in y_pred_before]
```